# Message returning object HTMLSpanElement in email

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Whenever i use a contact form on my website, everything is working fine except message. It is returning [object HTMLSpanElement]

Here is my code of mail.js i have created separate files because i am also using this file for error handling.

```
function submit_form()
{   
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
var message     =   document.getElementById('subject').value;

$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'enquiry.php',      
data:'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&contactno='+contactno+'&message='+message1,
success:function(data)
{
if(data=="1")
{
//document.getElementById('success').innerHTML="Your message has been sent successfully.";
$('#success').html("Your message has been sent successfully.")
```

**and here is the code of enquiry.php**

```
$name           =   $_POST['name'];
$email          =   $_POST['email'];
$contactno      =   $_POST['contactno'];
$message1       =   $_POST['message'];
$to         =   "emailaddress@email.com";
$subject    =   "Enquiry";
$from       =   "emailaddress@email.com";   
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>ENQUIRY</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>ENQUIRY</h4>
<b>Full Name</b>: $name<br />
<b>Email Id</b>: $email<br /> 
<b>Contact</b>: $contactno <br />
<b>Message </b>: $message1<br />
</body>
</html>";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from. ">" ;

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    echo 1;     
}
```

And here is the html for that

```
<input type="text" name="contactno" maxlength="10" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" id="contactno" placeholder="Enter 10 digit Contact Number" class="footer-form1" value="" onchange="removeerr();" required><br>
<span id="contact1"></span>                 

<textarea id="subject" name="message" id="subject" placeholder="Write your message here.." class="footer-massage" value="" onchange="removeerr();" required></textarea>
<span id="message1"></span>
<span id="success"></span>
```

Comment: Show us more of your JS code and the related HTML. More than likely, `message1` is an HTML element, not its text.

Answer (score 1):

When you send the data with:

```
data:'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&contactno='+contactno+'&message='+message1,
```

`message1` is a reference to the HTML `span` element with that `id`. Your message appears to be inside of the `textarea` element with an `id` of `subject` and you are correctly getting that data and storing it, but you are calling your variable `message` (not `message1`), so the line that sends the data should be:

```
data:'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&contactno='+contactno+'&message='+message,
```